# going back from an activity to a fragment inside an ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented a swipe tab with fragments in an ActionBarActivity(using pager adapter). in each fragment I have some imageViews that when I click, it goes to another activity and every thing is ok.

**in fragment:**

```
Img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity,
                    Activity.class);

            startActivity(mansoojatIntent);
        }
    });
```

The problem is **when i click back button in that activity to go back to the fragment, the application closes.**

**in activity:**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    finish();
}
```

**my manifest :**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.main.AbzarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        >
```

**UPDATE:**
the problem solved:
the line
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
in the manifest was the problem...!!

Comment: Show us your manifest too

Comment: what do you want on pressing back button?